# URL alias for a spicific link in my website using htaccess just like in weebly

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5, alias

it is possible to make an URL alias of a given link of my website? for example I have a page of:

```
wwww.myste.com/app/subname1
wwww.myste.com/app/subname2
wwww.myste.com/app/subname3
...
```

and it will be access as

```
wwww.subname1.myste.com/
wwww.subname2.myste.com/
wwww.subname3.myste.com/
...
```

is it possible in PHP and htaccess?

well, I am a developing a website system that will create also a subwebsite that will be access as subdomain, just like in weebly.com and wordpress.com.

is it really possible that it can be used in htaccess and PHP, if it is can you give me an example?

my website is hosted in mediatemple and the DNS is on godaddy. I know how o create a subdomain but it needs to go to godaddy and have it own directory in medatemple. But what I really want is that ones a user registered, it will creates it own link like `wwww.subname1.myste.com/` instead of `wwww.myste.com/app/subname1`. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled mod_rewrite, you could write into `<document root>/app/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^([^/]+)(.*)" "http://www.$1.example.com$2" [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect `/app/subname1/subfolder/file.html` to `www.subname1.example.com/subfolder/file.html`

The rewrite rule is a regular expression matching the path relative to the current directory. The initial `^` forces matching from the start of the subject. The parentheses `()` declare a subpattern stored in numbered placeholders `$1`... `[abc]` means any character of "a", "b" or "c". A `^` as first character within the brackets is a negation, so `[^abc]` means any character but "a", "b" or "c". The dot matches any character. `+` and `*` are multiplier, where `+` means **1** or more and `*` means **0** or more occurrences. Multipliers belong to the preceeding *expression*, not the result. So `[abc]+` matches as well to "aaaa" as also to "abca".

The second string is the target.

The third argument `[R=301,L]` means **R**edirection **301** (permanently moved); **L**ast rule on match.